# Pyplot plot image with colormap and sequence of alpha

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

With the [imshow](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) function from pyplot, I can plot an (M,N) size image, where each value in the (M,N) sized array is associated to a color from a colormap

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = np.random.rand(5,5)
plt.imshow(A, cmap='jet')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

I have an (2,M,N) sized array (let's call it `B`) that I would like to show.  `B[0]` gives the hue and `B[1]` is the alpha. Here, `B[0]` would be the same as `A` in the first example.

I would like to write something like `plt.imshow(B[0], cmap='jet', alpha=B[1])`. But the value of the `alpha` has to be the same for the entire image, since the `alpha` option has to be a scalar or None

With `imshow`, I can also specify an (M,N,3) or an (M,N,4) array, where the value for R,G,B and alpha are given. However, I don't know how to get the RGB values from my initial (M,N) sized array `A`.

---

I tried setting the color with the HSV scheme from my values, then converting to RGB and plotting with those colors

```
from matplotlib import colors

B = np.random.rand(2,5,5)

hue = B[0]
sat = B[1]
val = np.ones(B[0].shape)

rgb = colors.hsv_to_rgb(np.array([hue, sat, val]).T)

plt.imshow(rgb)
plt.show()
```

But then, I don't know how to make a color bar from the actual values in `B`.

---

I'm going for something like this:
[image: Expected result]
where the vertical part of the colorbar shows the value in `B[0]` and the horizontal part of the colorbar shows the value in `B[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

The first part is relatively straight forward:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = np.random.rand(5,5)
cmap = plt.get_cmap('jet')

rgba_img = cmap(A)
rgba_img[:, :, 3] = np.random.rand(5, 5)

plt.imshow(rgba_img)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Making a colorbar is more difficult. You will basically need to replace the pcolor that is used to make the colorbar with another one that looks as you want it to.

Comment: But here, the colorbar is has nothing to do with the data. The colorbar uses the viridis colormap, and the image uses the jet colormap